# Node-level graph-style traversal visualisation?

Tags: javascript, visualization, javascript-framework, data-visualization, graph-traversal

I am looking for a JavaScript library which can do node-level traversal of a graph.

The most similar thing I could find (to help explain what I want) is [ThinkMap](http://www.thinkmap.com), which is used by [visualthesaurus](http://www.visualthesaurus.com).

Basically starting from a single circular node (preferably a `<table>`) I would like to show a restricted number of nearest neighbours.

Clicking on a nearest neighbour should reframe the graph centering on the new node, and querying its JSON source for the new nearest neighbours.

**Are there any open-source JavaScript libraries or frameworks with an example doing something similar?**

Answer (score 0):

Is [this D3 example](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html) of any help to you?

Comment: I have seen similar, and they are quite nice; but don't allow you to drill down at all. Also, with no limit on number of nodes shown it would get out of hand rather immediately.